# How I use label as a countdown in Repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

My scenario is that. I have a repeater and item template has a span(label) I get some date from database and I want to show like countdown to customers.

I try to wrote like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
     var _second = 1000;
        var _minute = _second * 60;
        var _hour = _minute * 60;
        var _day = _hour * 24;
        var timer;

        $("#carCampaign span").each(function (index, value) {
            //alert(index);
            var data = $(this).attr('data');

            if (data == 'timer') {

                var end = $(this).attr('end');
                var date = new Date(end);

                function showRemaining() {
                    var now = new Date();
                    var distance = date - now;

                    if (distance < 0) {

                        clearInterval(timer);
                        document.getElementById('#Label3' + i).innerHTML = 'EXPIRED!';

                        return;
                    }
                    var hours = Math.floor((distance % _day) / _hour);
                    var minutes = Math.floor((distance % _hour) / _minute);
                    var seconds = Math.floor((distance % _minute) / _second);

                    document.getElementById('Label3').innerHTML = hours + 'hrs ';
                    document.getElementById('Label3').innerHTML += minutes + 'mins ';
                    document.getElementById('Label3').innerHTML += seconds + 'secs';
                    $(this).innerHTML = hours;


                }

                timer = setInterval(showRemaining, 1000);
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

And this is my .HTML

```
<div id="carCampaign">
            <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptOpportunities" OnItemDataBound="rptOpportunities_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptOpportunities_ItemCommand">
                <ItemTemplate>                        
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <a href="#anyword">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-md-4 search-img">
                                            <asp:Image ID="imageCar" itemprop="image" CssClass="img-responsive" runat="server" />
                                            <div class="row weight-700"><span class="fa fa-clock-o" style="padding-removed 15px;"></span> </div>
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="coming-soon-plugin" style="font-size: 2.2em; padding-removed 15px; margin-removed -35px;">
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="timer" Text='<%#Eval("DueDateTime") %>' data="timer" end='<%#Eval("DueDateTime") %>'>
                                                    </asp:Label>
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" />
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
                </div>
```

But that time just first span converted to coundown another does not work.
and I assume that every time countdown try to work the first span. Do you have any suggest?

Comment: i think you shouldn't use ID Label3 with Static ClientIDMode, maybe you can generate it with custom ID using Literal and use the custom ID that you made, not the static ID, because ID should be unique.

Comment: Okey I try without idmode thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

if I understand,  you want to create countdown timer for every date that is retrieved from database in repeater control.

If that is true , you can get help from below mention jQuery plugin.

[jQuery Countdown](http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html)

[25+ Best Free jQuery Countdown Timer Scripts and Plugins](http://weblees.com/free-jquery-countdown-timer-scripts/#.UqwHIifpxAc)

Hope it helps !!

Comment: Your right but something missing. I use some plugin in my page but I try to use multiple countdown?